# Unable to fetch result in Mysqli [Undefined offset ]

Tags: php, loops, binding, mysqli, fetch

This is my simple query and even it is not executing , 
my $total is 3;

```
$pnc = array();

$pnc[] = ('318','259','789');

$total = count($pnc);

for($p=0;$p<$total;$p++)
{
   echo $query = "select `id` from `patents` where `number`=?";
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) or $mysqli->error ;
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$pnc[$p]);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($id);
   $stmt->fetch();
   echo $id;
}
```

When i am echoing query i am getting

```
select `id` from `patents` where `number`='318'
```

and when i am running this query in phpmyadmin its getting 'id' value , but here it is unable to get the id,

Is this the problem occurs due to Undefined offset`bind_param("s",$pnc[$p]);` even i am getting value of each element of the array.

Please give a solution for this
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Change` -

```
$pnc = array();
$pnc[] = ('318','259','789');
$total = count($pnc);
```

**TO**

```
$pnc = array('318', '259', '789');
echo $total = count($pnc);
```

**Error**  in your code --> [Error](http://codepad.org/HXlvF9O3)

Comment: there is no problem in array the values are comming goog when i am var_dump() the array, but when i am passing this array value to bind values i am not getting even error , looks like everything is working fine , but with no result.

Comment: Thanks the value also has to change to codepage conversion UTF -8

Answer (score 0):

My guess is turned `error_reporting` off, because

```
 $pnc[] = ('318','259','789');
 $total = count($pnc);
```

is giving me a syntax error (PHP 5.4.7).

Try changing those two lines to:

```
$pnc = array('318','259','789');
$total = count($pnc);
```

Comment: thanks,Yes i have change that , and it is showing 3 as a count , but even i am not able to fetch the values from table and i have declared error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top,